# Get month name from value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I get the month name from the following value "2016-04-01 15:16:00.000"

I used the following SQL:

- The month number is correct
- The month name is not correct

[image]

```
SELECT [MyDate] AS [Raw Date]
      ,MONTH([MyDate]) AS [Month Number]
      ,DATENAME(mm,MONTH([MyDate])) AS [Month Name]
  FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the date into datename, not the month number...

`DATENAME(mm, [MyDate])`